# grouping and simplifying multiple if conditions / bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have multiple If conditions to to run at the beginning of the script

```
if blah; then
echo "hop"
fi
if [ ! -f blah-blah ]; then
echo "hop-hop"
else
echo "hip-hop-hap"
fi
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "hip-hop"
fi
```

each of this conditions
are separate from each other, and I have them 7-8
so I'm thinking if there is some way to group them...
I was thinking to use 
`elif` , but `elif` will stop checking conditions if one of them is truth,
any suggestion would be ppreciated

Comment: if they are not mutually exclusive or end up with the same action you can't further simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to give a definitive answer to a question that asks for *some way*.

Here is an alternative idea. We create an array of boolean values that contains the results of evaluation of logical conditions. And for each
condition `i` define a pair of functions `func${i}0` and `func${i}1` that will be called when condition `i` evaluates to true or false respectively. Finally we loop through our boolean array.

The code below implements this idea. It is rather awkward. Feel free to suggest improvements or downvote.

Here we assume that `blah` evaluates to either 0 or 1.

```
# populate array b by evaluating boolean conditions 
foo=$( blah );                b[1]=$?
foo=$( [ ! -f blah-blah ] );  b[2]=$?
foo=$( [ $? -eq 0 ] );        b[3]=$?

# For each condition 1 through 3 define the actions when
# the condition is True or False
func10(){
echo "hop"
}
func11(){ :;}

func20(){
    echo "hop-hop"
}
func21(){
    echo "hip-hop-hap"
}

func30(){
    echo "hip-hop"
}
func31(){ :;}

#loop through the array and execute the functions 
for i in $(seq 1 ${#b[*]}) ; do
func${i}${b[i]}
done
```

**Edits:**

1. Replaced `{(:)}` by `{ :;}` per Charles Duffy suggestion
2. The use of `$(seq)` in the loop is inefficient, yet explicitly
   incrementing the loop counter seems a bit too much to type.

Comment: What purpose do the command substitutions serve? Likewise, why pay the performance cost of a subshell for `{(:)}` rather than `{ :; }`?

Answer (score 1):

If what you are hoping for is shorter code, you could do something like this :

```
blah && echo "hop"
[ -f "blah-blah" ] && echo "hip-hop-hap" || echo "hop-hop"
[ $? = 0 ] && echo "hip-hop"
```

This is not "simpler" in the logical sense, but it is more concise.

Please note that I removed the `!` from the test and switched the resulting statements as a small optimization.

Please note, however, that if you want to perform any kind of error checking or explicit handling (i.e. `trap ... ERR`, `set -e`), then using logical operators is going to interfere with that and you will not be able to tell the difference between a bug in your script and a command that fails for "good reasons" (i.e. attempting to delete a non-existing file).  You are probably mostly safe if you restrict yourself to `echo` statements, or if, like most shell programmers, you allow the shell to simply ignore failed statements (which is not, in my opinion, a good way to build predictable and reliable shell code).